# Xubuntu locking screen, then closing laptop lid and reopening opens a generic lightdm greeter instance

Tags: xubuntu, laptop, lightdm, lock-screen

1. lock screen in Xubuntu
2. Closing laptop lid
3. Reopening the lid a generic (blue) lightdm greeter instance appears with only a password prompt and no user list. No password seems to unlock it

Currently in battery settings "Laptop Lid - When laptop lid is closed:" is set to "Lock Screen". So it seems it's "double" locking the screen?

The first lock screen is the custom one set up (custom theme, has user list, passwords), the lightdm blue greeter screen only has a password prompt and does not work.

How can I remove this "extra" screen or at least login?

Comment: Xubuntu uses `light-locker` which does show the lightdm login screen when it locks the system. Have you tried closing the lid without locking the system manually first to check if you can unlock it correctly afterwards?

Comment: Without locking first, then closing the lid, it does work as intended (using my customized, user list, lock screen)

Just wondering why if I lock before closing lid it does this.